are "I will check your homework later" and "I will check on your homework later" similar?
I often ask my children to do homework and after that, what would I say "I will check your homework later" and  "I will check on your homework later"?
Someone on Quora told me "check your homework" implies checking for errors or mistakes while "check on your homework" implies checking to see how much homework you have done.
However, another one said "check your homework" is valid but "check on your homework" is not used. Instead of saying "check on your homework", we say "check on you" (to make sure you are doing homework).
Is that correct?

I agree with that.

That's reasonable, but as with most fairly relaxed use of English, don't expect a clear separation of meaning.

Yes, that is correct in this context.
Checking something usually means validating that it meets some specific criteria (e.g., homework answers are right or wrong). Checking on something usually means checking the status of something (e.g., homework has been started or is finished). A similar example:

I need to check the maid's cleaning.
I need to check on the maid.

In the first sentence, you're checking the quality of the work the maid has done. In the second sentence, you're checking on the status of the maid (for example, has she started? is she done?).
I think it's important to note that in these examples, what you're checking and what you're checking on are two different things. There are cases, however, where what you check and what you check on are essentially the same. In that case, you can use either. For example:

I need to check the turkey.
I need to check on the turkey.

In both cases, you are presumably checking to see if the turkey is done so you can eat dinner. Checking the turkey might mean checking its temperature, but that's essentially the same as checking its cooking status.

However, another native English speaker said "check your homework" is valid but "check on your homework" is not used. Instead of saying "check on your homework", we say "check on you" (to make sure you are doing homework).

@Tom That hasn't been addressed directly yet, but both these answers should show that, IMO, this person is wrong. "Check on your homework" is a reasonable shorthand for "Check on [the progress of] your homework."

@AndyBonner I have to disagree with that. Checking on homework is very odd to me. I can’t explain why exactly checking on the turkey is fine while checking on homework isn’t, but that’s how it is to me. Checking on something is equivalent to checking how something is doing (≈ its status), and there again it’s perfectly fine to say, “I need to check how the turkey is doing [in the oven]”, but “I need to check how your homework is doing” is very strange. Perhaps something to do with whether the status/progression is directly acted on by a person?

@JanusBahsJacquet That's fine, but it works for me. I actually said it the other day!

"to check {something}" is to examine it for quality, irregularities, errors, conformity, etc.

Check the fuel-line to make sure it's not kinked.
Can you check my math?

"to check on {someone, something}" is to examine it/them in order to ascertain its/their current condition or state.

Before we start the movie, I'm going to check on the baby.
I'm going down to the basement to check on the hot water heater.

"to check in on {someone}" is to visit them with the intention of checking on them.
